# How can I make C++ algorithms fuse?

Tags: c++, stl, functional-programming, stl-algorithm

Consider the following C++ program to print the smallest adjacent difference given a vector of numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers = { 10, 1, 43, 59, 78, 46, 63, 12 };

    std::vector<int> deltas;
    std::adjacent_difference( numbers.begin(),
                              numbers.end(),
                              std::back_inserter( deltas ) );

    auto minEl = std::min_element( deltas.begin() + 1,
                                   deltas.end() );

    std::cout << *minEl;
}
```

I'd like to get rid of the intermediate `deltas` vector but still continue using `std::adjacent_difference` and `std::min_element` (instead of looping myself).

In functional languages, the elemination of intermediate data structures is often called [deforestation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deforestation_(computer_science)) (or "fusion"). Is there a common way to do the same in C++?

I imagine it might be possible to devise some sort of iterator wrapper which allows incrementally computing the adjacent differences as `min_element` iterates the range. I couldn't find anything like that in the standard libraries though. Maybe some 3rd party library (Boost?) offers something like that?

Comment: I'd say you're either looking for Boost's [`transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) or custom use of Boost's [iterator facade and adaptors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html#iterator-facade-and-adaptor).

Comment: Deforestation seems to involve extracting iterative steps from two or more algorithms and intermingling them, i.e. AAAABBBB -> ABABABAB. This doesn't seem like a feasible compiler optimization in C++, and the standard library doesn't have the "one step of the algorithm" operation (a shame! Both adjacent_difference and min_element should have been iterator adapters rather than algorithms). So you pretty much have to reimplement at least one of the algorithms so that there's a reusable "step" entity.

Comment: Check out [Eric Niebler's range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), which he is using as the basis of a standard proposal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing (and hoping) you'll get some better answers, but here's an approach if you're keen enough to flesh out a little library of helper code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
struct min
{
    typedef T element_type;
    min(int& min) : min_(min) { }
    min& operator *() { return *this; }
    min& operator=(const T& t)
    {
        if (first_)
            min_ = t, first_ = false;
        else if (t < min_)
            min_ = t;
    }
    min& operator++() { return *this; }
    bool first_ = true;
    T& min_;
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct skip_take  // i.e. skip some elements, take some elements...
{
    skip_take(Iterator i, size_t skip, size_t take = size_t(-1))
      : i_(i), skip_(skip), take_(take)
    { }
    skip_take& operator *() { return *this; }
    skip_take& operator=(const typename Iterator::element_type& t)
        { if (skip_ == 0 && take_) *i_ = t; }
    skip_take& operator++()
        { if (skip_) --skip_; else if (take_) --take_, ++i_; return *this; }
    Iterator& i_;
    size_t skip_, take_;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers = { 10, 1, 43, 59, 78, 46, 63, 12 };

    int result;
    std::adjacent_difference(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
                             skip_take<min<int>>(min<int>(result), 1));

    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

(Code on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/t55UGU))

More generally, good implementations for this kind of thing are frustrated a bit by C++'s lack of coroutines (which are used by lazy generators in many other languages - there was a boost library or proposal for this floating around - not sure how usable), and the Standard Library's preference for iterators over ranges (making it harder for one algo to return the range the next algo should operate on).  There are plenty of "functional" libraries for C++ that use template expressions and other techniques far more sophisticated than the code above to good effect.

Comment: Alas, this reimplements the `std::min_element` algorithm instead of reusing it. +1 for the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can write your own class to provide an output iterator. You can then override the dereference and increment operators to do the calculation you want. It is a hack though, probably just writing afor loop is the best solution.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

class Something;

struct SomethingIter {
   SomethingIter(Something* p) : parent(p) {};
   SomethingIter& operator++();
   int& operator* ();
private:
   Something* parent;
};

class Something {
public:   
   Something() : minset(false), first(true), min(0) { }
   SomethingIter storage() {
      SomethingIter ret(this);
      return ret;
   }
   void set() {
      if (first) { first = false; }
      else if (!minset || s < min) {
     min = s;
     minset = true;
      }
   }
   int& value() { return s; }
   int getMin() const { return min; }
private:
   bool first;
   bool minset;
   int min;
   int s;
};

SomethingIter& SomethingIter::operator++() {
   parent->set();
   return *this;
}

int& SomethingIter::operator* () {
   return parent->value();
}


int main() {
   Something s;
   vector<int> values{ 0, 2, 5 };
   adjacent_difference(values.begin(), values.end(), s.storage());
   cout << "min: " << s.getMin() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

**But why complicate things?**

First use case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int minDiff(const vector<int>& values) {
   size_t len = values.size();
   if (len < 2) { throw runtime_error("Invalid vector"); }
   int mindiff = values[1] - values[0];
   for (size_t i = 2; i<len; ++i) {
      int diff = values[i] - values[i-1];
      if (diff < mindiff) { mindiff = diff; }
   }
   return mindiff;
}

int main() {
   vector<int> values{0, 2, 5};  
   cout << minDiff(values) << endl;      
   return 0;
}
```

Second use case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   vector<string> A{"AB", "BA", "AAA"};

   unsigned int sum = 0;
   for_each (A.begin(), A.end(), [&sum](const string& s) {
     if (s[0] == 'A') { sum += s.length(); } });
   cout << sum << endl;


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the requirement of reusing the `std::min_element` algorithm though.

Comment: I assumed you the part that you didn't like was the fact that in your example you created a list of diffs (space complexity of O(n) when O(1) should be enough). Now I understand its more of a posed hypothetical used as a tool to critique C++ and not a real question. I'm sorry I wasted my time.

Comment: It wasn't a hypothetical question at all, it is indeed the linear space usage which I want to get rid of. However, I want to get rid of intermediate data structures without having to reimplement any of the algorithms myself. I'd like to reuse library functions like `std::min_element` without having to sacrifice performance. In your code, you basically reimplement the "Is this element smaller than the smallest I've seen so far?" logic of `std::min_element` in the `Something::set` method. That's the part I want to avoid.

Comment: Another usecase, involving three standard algorithms: sum (`std::accumulate`) the lengths of (`std::transform`) all strings in some vector starting with `A` (`std::copy_if`). It would be great if I could somehow reuse these algorithms without having two intermediate vectors of strings.

Comment: 'std::min_element` function takes a list and iterates through it finding the minimum. You can solve your problem without creating a list, so why would you insist on using that function? The functions in the standard library are additional tools provided by the language, if they fit your needs you use them, if they don't, you implement your own.